# 戻り値SKAnimateをrunさせたい

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

いつもお世話になっております。

複数あるアクションの中から特定のアクションを取得し、sequenceで順次runさせたいと考えております。

```
let actionSequence = SKAction.sequence([
    pN.animate(named: "walk"),
    pN.animate(named: "wait"),
    pN.animate(named: "turn"),
    pN.animate(named: "walk"),
])
pN.run(actionSequence)
```

戻り値をprint(type(of: xxx))で調べましたら、SKAnimateと表示されました。
ですが戻り値をSKAnimate型にすると

```
use of undeclared type 'SKAnimate'
```

と表示されます。
戻り値をSKActionやAnyObject型で試しましたが、アニメーションできませんでした。
試しに、sequenceせずに1つのアクションで検証してみましたがダメでした。

```
pN.run(pN.animate(named: "walk") as! SKAction, withKey: "walk")
```

SKAnimateについて調べましたが、解決策に辿り着くことができませんでした。
どうかご教授ご鞭撻のほどよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: そもそもあなたのコードの中の`pN`とは何型で、`animate(named:)`メソッドはどのように定義されているのでしょうか？「戻り値をprint(type(of: xxx))で調べました」とありますが、あなたのコードの中には`xxx`などありませんが、一体何の戻り値を調べたのでしょうか？「戻り値をSKActionやAnyObject型で試しました」とありますが、ここでの「試した」は何を表しているのでしょうか？「アニメーションできませんでした」「ダメでした」というのはコンパイルエラーになるのですか、実行時エラーになるのですか、それとも実行できるが結果が期待と異なるのですか？とにかくわからないことだらけで、わからないです、というコメント以外何も書けません。もう少し情報を整理して読む人にとって必要な情報をきちんと記載してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご返信ありがとうございます。
結果から申しますと凡ミスしており解決致しました。

ソースが大きかった為、当方が悩んでいる箇所を抜粋し簡略化し記載させて頂きました。
ですが、簡略化し過ぎ逆にご回答者様を悩ませてしまいました。
申し訳ございません。

print(type(of: xxx))は、print(type(of: 戻り値))を表現したものになります。

```
func animate(named: String) -> SKAction! {  // 戻り値をSKAnimateにしたらuse of undeclared type 'SKAnimate'
    let a = SKAction.animate(with: xxx as! [SKTexture], timePerFrame: 0.033)
    print(type(of: a))  // SKAnimate
    return a
}
```

SKAnimateの戻り値はSKActionでしたので、上記戻り値はSKActionで解決致しました。
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction/1417828-animate

「アニメーションできませんでした、ダメでした」は、コンパイルは通りましたが、戻り値のSKActionを再生することができなかった次第です。

```
pN.run(pN.animate(named: "walk") as! SKAction, withKey: "walk")  // アニメーションしてくれなかった
```

凡ミス箇所を記載させて頂きたいと思います。

```
class A {
    private var aP: String
    init() {
        self.aP = "a"
    }
    func aM() -> String {
        return self.aP
    }
}
class B {
    //private var node: A
    var node: A  // pubに致しました
    init() {
        node = A()
    }
    func animate(named: String) -> SKAction! {
        let a = SKAction.animate(with: xxx as! [SKTexture], timePerFrame: 0.033)
        return a
    }
}

let pN = B()
let a = pN.animate(named: "walk")
//pN.run(a)       // ご質問はここにあたります(コンパイルは通るけどアニメーションされない)
print(pN.node.aM())
pN.node.run(a)  // 凡ミスにより解決しアニメーションさせることができました
```

nに対しrunを実行させようとしておりました。
簡単ではございますが当方の凡ミスでございました。

以上よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。正直、私の知らないクラスに`animate(named:)`と言うメソッドがあるのかと思って、かなりの時間をかけて探してしまいました…。`A`は実際には`SKNode`か何かのサブクラスでしょうか?実アプリレベルの大きなソースを差し障りのない範囲で再編集していただくのはかなり大変だったかと思いますが、そこら辺の肝になる情報が欠けていますと、せっかくの回答も活用される機会が少なくなってしまいます。できればその辺は質問・回答に限らず明示していただければと思います。なお、質問に対して直接解決に結びつく回答には「承認」のチェックをお願いします。(ご自分の回答に対しては、少し時間をおかないと承認できないかもしれません。)

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。当方の質問内容に不備があり、貴重なお時間を不意にしてしまい大変申し訳ございません。今後は質問内容を精査して記載していきたいと思います。ご察しの通りにクラスAはSKNodeを継承しておりました。「承認」チェックについてアドバイス頂きありがとうございます。システム把握していなく申し訳ございません。探してチェック入れておきたいと思います。

Comment: 愚痴みたいなことを書き込んだのは、今後、このサイトでご質問やご回答を書き込んでいただくときに改善の動機付けにしていただきたいという思いからですので、どうか過剰にお気になさらないでください。クラス`A`が`SKNode`を継承している件については、`run`メソッドが正しく呼べるかと言う根幹に当たる事柄なので、ご回答を編集して、そのことも含めていただければと思います。